# How to read structural rules

Tags: logic, notation

In the wikipedia page on [structural rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule), we have the following "weakening" rule.

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash \Sigma}{\Gamma \vdash A, \Sigma}$$

This makes no sense to me. It seems to be saying that, if, in some context $\Gamma$, we can deduce $\Sigma$, then we can also deduce $A,\Sigma$ in that context. So in particular, in every context $\Gamma$ we can deduce any sentence $A$.

How are structural rules *actually* meant to be read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In sequent calculus the intended meaning of a sequent $A_1,\dotsc,A_n\vdash B_1,\dotsc, B_m$ is $\lbrace A_1,\dotsc,A_n\rbrace \vDash_L B_1 \vee\dotsc\vee B_m$ where $\vDash_L$ means "logical inference".

Comment: Ah, of course. Should have worked that one out myself!